# Cannot start Apache, config test fail: "env: apache2ctl: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

**My Ubuntu version is 14.04.**

I was fixing a few things on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and then the next time I restarted Apache, I keep getting this weird error:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2      [fail]                                                                          * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
env: apache2ctl: No such file or directory
```

I also reverted all the changes in `000-default.conf`, but the issue is not getting resolved.

I do not understand how I might have caused this issue and also I don't know how to resolve it.

Help would be highly appreciated.

---

**Latest Apache error logs:**

```
[Sun Jun 05 11:50:26.341221 2016] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 6035:tid 118764177487744] AH00292: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 05 11:50:26.341266 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6035:tid 118764177487744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jun 05 12:15:51.071093 2016] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 6035:tid 118764177487744] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: What is in the Apache error log?

Comment: @Colt I updated the question with the latest logs. The same logs are repeated over and over a couple times in the log file.

Comment: and `apache2ctl -t` ?

Comment: Wow! It says `The program 'apache2ctl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install apache2`, but it was working earlier as expected? I'm really confused now.

Comment: what does `sudo ls -la /usr/sbin/apache*` return?

Comment: @Colt the command above returns this: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637528 Jan 14 18:46 /usr/sbin/apache2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `apache2ctl` script and the symlink for `apachectl`. For Ubuntu 14.04, both should be in the `/usr/sbin/` directory with the following dates (normal installation, upgrades) and permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6402 Jan  3  2014 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     10 Jan 14 17:46 /usr/sbin/apachectl -> apache2ctl
```

If you have a backup of your system, you should recover. If not, you will need to repair the Apache2 installation.

**NOTE ALSO**: The `/usr/sbin/` directory is a *shared* directory holding all scripts generally accessible with root privileges. Given that you do not know *how* the `apache2` files went missing, you *could* have problems beyond this issue or even beyond `apache2`.

Comment: What would be the best way to _repair_ the Apache2 installation?

Comment: Given that you do not know _what_ happened to the missing files, _or what other files may be messed up_, you probably need to consider [removing _or_ purging](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) the `apache2` package and installing it again. Depending on how you proceed, your configuration and site files may be lost on the server, so **make sure you have a backup of all of _your_ files and configured `apache2` files**.

Answer (score 0):

> env: apache2ctl: No such file or directory

I don't have an Ubuntu system to hand but it looks like the PATH may be malformed and [`env`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) cannot find `apache2ctl`.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem for me was running the command (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

which installed the missing apache2ctl while keeping everything else untouched.